# number matching game with jquery. the second selection is affected the the previous selection

Tags: jquery

This is the jquery code. After the first selections turn green, the second selection renders the li of the first selection red.

```
$(“#list1).on(“click”,”li”, function(){
var nomber = $(this);
$(“#list2”).on(“click”,”li”, function(){
var nombre = $(this);
if(nombre.text() === nomber.text()){
nomber.css(“color”, “green”);
nombre.css(“color”, “green”);
}else{
nomber.css(“color”, “red”);
nombre.css(“color”, “red”);
}
}
```

This is the html code

```
<ul id = “list1”>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul id = “list2”>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i dont understant where is your problem..

Comment: What's your actual question? What problems are you having? What error codes are you getting? Really, what's wrong? You need to explain that to us, not just assume we can figure it out by your code.

Comment: It’s not throwing any errors, however when the first selection shows that the two numbers selected are correct, the second selection changes the color of the previously selected numbers

Comment: First selection 1 and 1 (both turn green). Second selection 2 and 2(both turn green) but first 1 in previous selection turns red.

Comment: Please I hope this explanation  is clearer.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the script remember the first and second selection, independently from each other. You can nest your click event listeners inside each other, but that's not a good coding practice. After your first and second numbers are picked and they are wrong, you need to forget the numbers. Then, if your numbers match, you may as well turn the number on the other list green as well.

See below example. It's made so you can select a number from either list1 or list2 first.

```js
// global variable; where the first selected number will be saved
window.first_selected_number = null;
// create a click listener on all <li> on list1
$('#list1 li').click(function() {
  // this will remember the first number selected
  window.first_selected_number = $(this).text();
  // if the first and second number match exactly
  if (window.first_selected_number === window.second_selected_number) {
    // set text color of this <li> to green
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
    // loops through second list to find the matching number
    // if numbers match, sets the <li> text color of the second list to green
    $('#list2 li').each(function() {
      var is_matching_number = $(this).text() === window.first_selected_number;
      if (is_matching_number) {$(this).css('color', 'green');}
    });
    // forgets the first and second numbers
    window.first_selected_number = null;
    window.second_selected_number = null;
  }
  // if the first and second number were set but did not match
  else if (window.first_selected_number && window.second_selected_number) {
    // set text color of this <li> to red
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    // forgets the first and second numbers
    window.first_selected_number = null;
    window.second_selected_number = null;
  }
  // if either the first or second number was not set
  else {
    // reverts the color back to what it was before it was changed
    $(this).css('color', 'initial');
  }
});


// this is same logic as the first list, but with the second number as the main focus
window.second_selected_number = null;
$('#list2 li').click(function() {
  window.second_selected_number = $(this).text();
  if (window.first_selected_number === window.second_selected_number) {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
    $('#list1 li').each(function() {
      var is_matching_number = $(this).text() === window.second_selected_number;
      if (is_matching_number) {$(this).css('color', 'green');}
    });
    window.first_selected_number = null;
    window.second_selected_number = null;
  }
  else if (window.first_selected_number && window.second_selected_number) {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    window.first_selected_number = null;
    window.second_selected_number = null;
  }
  else {
    $(this).css('color', 'initial');
  }
});
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c8pryd59/

Comment: Thank you so much again, you literally saved me

Comment: Hi I have another problem. This code is not running 
if($("#list2 div")=== null){
$(".message").append("Well Done");
https://jsfiddle.net/k91d6gu7/

Comment: I modified the js fiddle link you sent to match my code. The code I sent from the previous comment is in the modified js fiddle jquery codes. Thank you ones again

Comment: You had several typos in your code. Using the `value` attribute on `<div>` is not valid HTML code. I updated it to use `data-` prefixed attribute, which is valid.
See code here: https://jsfiddle.net/q8avxnsc/1/